# Stopwatch resets when activity restarts

Tags: java, android, android-activity, stopwatch

I`m trying to create simple stopwatch for my statistics activity. What it needs to do is start when activity creates for the first time and then count and count until i reset it. The code I used:

```
    String trip_time;
    long millis;
    long start_time;
    Handler Handler;
    private boolean started = false;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 10L);
        if (!started) {
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            started = true;
        }
     }

  private final Runnable Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            millis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);
            long seconds = millis / 1000;
            trip_time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
            Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 10L);
        }
    };
```

But when I come to activity with intent, or activity restarts Stopwatch resets and starts counting from 0. After a few resets it continues counting from basic time. Can I somehow get rid of this problem? Probably via class or whatever.

Comment: you can add your timer in the ViewModel class and getting time in the activity. So when the activity recreates, configuration changes, etc then your data does not destory.

Comment: you have to save the class variables onSaveInstanceState an restore them in  onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, I solved my problem via making StopwatchService:

```
public class StopwatchService extends Service {

    Handler Handler;
    long start_time;
    static String trip_time;
    static long millis;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Handler = new Handler();
        Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 10L);
        start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }
    private final Runnable Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            millis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);
            long seconds = millis / 1000;
            trip_time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
            Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 10L);
        }
    };
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public static String getTrip_time(){return trip_time;}
}
```

In manifest:

```
 <service 
    android:name=".StopwatchService"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

And in activity:

```
 startService(new Intent(this, StopwatchService.class));
 String trip_time = StopwatchService.getTrip_time();
```

Comment: That's great. Can you upvote my answer then?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have enough reputation to vote

Answer (score 0):

The following code will reset the stopwatch every time because when you come back to this activity, it will start a new runnable and show that on UI.

You need something that will connect to the previous data. You can use **Service** that will bind every time you return to this activity even if your app is removed from the background. Or you can save the last time and elapsed time on **Shared Preferences / Datastore** and start the activity timer by adding the total elapsed time.

Comment: Can you please provide any code of how to make it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can refer if you specify which way you want to implement the feature.